# Error in r.terraflow

Tags: grass-gis, hydrography

I used r.terraflow.short in GRASS, but it displayed this error:

```
r.terraflow.short elevation=raster_bulacanElevation \
                  filled=raster_bulacanElevationFlooded1 \
                  direction=raster_bulacanElevationFlowDirection1 \
                  swatershed=raster_bulacanElevationSink1 \  
                  accumulation=raster_bulacanElevationAccumulation1 \
                  tci=raster_bulacanElevationTCI1
stats.out: Permission denied
STREAM temporary files in C:/Users/Rhen/AppData/Local/Temp
(THESE INTERMEDIATE STREAMS WILL NOT BE DELETED IN CASE OF
ABNORMAL TERMINATION OF THE PROGRAM. TO SAVE SPACE PLEASE
DELETE THESE FILES MANUALLY!)
```

What should I do to make r.terraflow.short run? I tried deleting all the contents of the Temp folder but GRASS still displayed the same error.

Comment: Which version of GRASS are you running? How did you install it? Based on your path name, I can assume windows, but not much beyond that.

Comment: I installed GRASS 6.4.0 in Windows. I downloaded it from the GRASS website

Answer (score 1):

Your issue could be related to bug http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/775. That's strange because it is supposed to be fixed since grass v6.4

Anyway, you can try to apply the patch ..

Comment: You can get a winGRASS version of 6.4 containing the fix here: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/775

Comment: @teamAngat: did you end up getting this to work OK, or do we need to keep looking for answers?

Comment: I have same problem, using ver. 6.4.3RC2 for windows

Answer (score 0):

we are also stuck with grass64 for some compatibility issues. For those still looking for a solution, the workaround is to change the name of the stats.out file by adding the parameter e.g. "stats=stats.out2" in the command. It should look like:

```
r.terraflow.short elevation=raster_bulacanElevation \
                  filled=raster_bulacanElevationFlooded1 \
                  direction=raster_bulacanElevationFlowDirection1 \
                  swatershed=raster_bulacanElevationSink1 \  
                  accumulation=raster_bulacanElevationAccumulation1 \
                  tci=raster_bulacanElevationTCI1 \
                  stats=stats.out2
```